# It is possible to check if cookie value equal to visitor user-agent using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

It is possible to check if cookie value equal to visitor user-agent using htaccess?

For example, I store user-agent in cookie called "_test", and I want to check if the cookie named "_test" == Guest_User_Agent.

I tried to do this below:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Cookie _test=^User-Agent$ whitelist
Deny from all
allow from env=whitelist
```

But it doesn't work.  Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable on right hand side. You can use `RewriteCond` directive to do the same result. You can compare the http request headers `cookie` and `user-agent` as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} _test="?([^;]*)"? 
RewriteCond %1##%{HTTP:User-Agent} !^(.*)##\1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Here the `RewriteCond` left hand side are joining two variables by delimiter `##`, the `%1` back-reference matching the cookie value `_test` and the second variable `User-Agent`. Then on right hand side we match and capture the value before `##` and using a back-reference `\1` to do the matching. If they have different value then gives the http 404 response code.